# How to decrypt the password stored in drupal to wordpress database?

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal

I am having forgot password form which is in drupal once user click the save button need to save the changed password in wordpress database user table. how to achieve it?

```
function wp_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
//echo "hi";

    if($form_id=="user_profile_form"){

        print '<pre>';
        //print_r($form);
        print_r($form_state['user']);
        echo $form_state['user']->uid;
        echo $form_state['user']->name;
        echo $form_state['user']->mail;
        echo $form_state['user']->pass;
        echo $form_state['user']->login;
        exit;
        //UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = md5($new_password) WHERE ID = $user_id


    }
}
```

Comment: you can't "decrypt" md5. What is your problem exactly? Which part is not working?

Comment: Not possible basically. One possible way is to list all possibilities and write a short code to try it: rude crack.

Comment: Why do you need to decrypt anything? You're just overwriting the old password.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can read submitted values from hook_form_alter() directly. Instead I think that you should add (register) your custom submission form handler from there:

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_handler';
```

And then make another function called that way ("my_custom_submit_handler()"), so when form is submitter your custom submission form handler will be also called and you can collect password data and save it.

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2010-01-29/adding-custom-submit-handlers-to-a

Answer (score 0):

```
What you can do is:

Setting the password to a random value, using user_hash_password()
Show a message to the users telling them they need to reset their password
The right way to call user_hash_password() is the following one.

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
$hash = user_hash_password($password);
```